# Pass VBA Variable into Access Query(Excel VBA)

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

Im new at trying to construct queries out of vba. I am trying to figure out how to pass a variable inside the VBA syntax. Mind showing me where im dumb?

I tried this below but there's an automation error that pops up. Ive noticed from playing aroudn that automation errors come up when youve just got syntax wrong, so hopefully its something small?

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
Sub GetDataFromAccess()
   Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command, rs As ADODB.Recordset
   Dim recordNum As Integer

   recordNum = 7

   cmd.ActiveConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Ashleysaurus\Desktop" & "\" & "xyzmanu3.accdb"
   cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE OrderNumber <" & "'" & recordNum & "'" & "ORDER BY OrderNumber ASC"

   Set rs = cmd.Execute
   Sheet1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

   rs.Close
   cmd.ActiveConnection.Close

   Debug.Print "Done!"
End Sub
```

Comment: do you put single quotes around numbers? `...er < " & recordNum & " ORD...` make sure you put the spaces inside the quotes in or the string gets all jumbled together.

Comment: Spaces did it, geez i knew it was something simple. I even removed the single quotes b/c they werent necessary. Post as an answer and receive delicious feedbacks :)

Comment: ah, give it to Paul X, I am feeling lazy today.

Comment: @ScottCraner youre such a generous guy lol

Comment: Thanks--though for future reference it was the removal of the single quotes that fixed it, not the spacing--you can't compare number to string, while >'x'ORDER BY would have been ok (even without the space) if it was a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming OrderNumber is a number, do not use quotes.
Also make sure you have a space before Order By:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE OrderNumber <" & recordNum & " ORDER BY OrderNumber ASC"
```

Comment: you forgot a quote but you get feedbacks when itll let me check it as answered

Answer (score 4):

While learning to build VBA queries, consider parameterized queries and avoid any need of quotes! This is an industry best practice across all languages when passing values in dynamic SQL queries.

```vb
Sub GetDataFromAccess()
   Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command, rs As ADODB.Recordset
   Dim recordNum As Integer

   recordNum = 7

   With cmd
       .ActiveConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                 & "Data Source=C:\Users\Ashleysaurus\Desktop" & "\" & "xyzmanu3.accdb"
       .CommandType = adCmdText
       .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Invoice" _
                        & " WHERE OrderNumber < ? ORDER BY OrderNumber ASC"    
   End With

   cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("recordNumParam", adInteger, adParamInput, 10)
   cmd.Parameters(0).Value = recordNum

   Set rs = cmd.Execute
   Sheet1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

   rs.Close
   cmd.ActiveConnection.Close

   Debug.Print "Done!"

End Sub
```

Comment: As much as I love this feedback, its a bit beyond my current level at the moment. I will save this link and learn to adjust, but currently i am still learning how to "make it work" ya know?

Comment: if you want to link me some documentation to help me along that would be swell

Comment: I hear you. Learn it as you go. Google is your friend on *parameterized queries* as there are many, many, many tutorials, blogs, posts, other SO answers on its use and importance